# How do we express people with very special hair styles, for example, "he is wearing his hair in 3 bamboo trees"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

We often say "**she is wearing her hair in braids/bunches/a ponytail**".

How do we express people with very special hair styles, for example, "**he is wearing his hair in 3 bamboo trees**" as shown in the picture?

[image]

Comment: Since such a hairstyle is unique, there is hardly likely to be a standard expression to describe it.

Comment: Aren't they **braids**? Perhaps here, *elaborate* braids.

Comment: There are no bamboo trees and we do not "express people". Those are just green dreads. We say; She has dreads or is wearing extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are called dreads or dreadlocks, styled dreadlocks:

[dreadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreadlocks)

They can come in many colors and types. And they are often grouped together to form a new dread style. Dreadlock styles can get very competitive....

When a person doesn't have enough of their own hair, extensions are used. That's the case with many people.

for example:

[image]

football players [soccer] have crazy styles sometimes. They like to stand out.

Like this. This is Neymar with dread extensions:

[image: NEYMAR]